# Newsletter border error

Tags: html, css, media, newsletter

I was try to create a responsive email template.everything work fine,except image border.
I set border for an image and media styles.but in small screen,image border will be crpped.

**HTML**

```
     <html>  
      <head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .message_mobile {
  width: 100% !important;
  }
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body  id="message_body" style="background-color:white;" >
     <table style="border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; width: 600px; display: table;" align="center" class="message_mobile"><tbody><tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:center;">
                      <div>
                        <img src="http://www.myfico.com/Images/sample_overlay.gif" alt=" " style="border: 16px solid rgb(196, 45, 196); display: block; width: 100%; padding: 2px; max-width: 94.64882943143813%;" width="auto">
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
         </td>
         </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output (Large screen)**
[image]

**Output (Small Screen)**

[image]

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YytAG/embedded/result/)**

Comment: why not make the image width slightly smaller ie 90%; ? because the width of the image is: width+borderwidth thus final width>100%

Comment: @user2211216 We can reduce image width.But the width need to be responsive

Comment: if you set it to 89% it works fine and it is responsive

Comment: @user2211216 But the border width is dynamic,it can be 1 to 99 px

Comment: i see that you have specified the border-width at 16px so it is not dynamic, im i getting it wrong?

Comment: @user2211216 for an example,i put 16 px.that may be 1px or between 1px to 100px

Answer (score 1):

You could set [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to `border-box`, however since this is a relatively new property, not all browsers (especially email clients) may support it.

Comment: Is it support in mobile browsers?Do you know?

Comment: Check the MDN link in my answer and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing . Both have infos on which broswers support it.